# CSS Selector :after

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, 1 floats left the other right.

I need to add a clearfix after the right float and have been reading up on using the :after selector.

I've tried to create this style and add the relevant attributes only it doesnt seem to work, am I understanding this rule incorrectly?

Any advice would be great!

http://jsfiddle.net/hjP6f/

Comment: be aware that `:after` doesn't work in IE7 or earlier.

Comment: @Liam: Please also include your code in your question, even if you're providing a link to a live example. That way, your question, when answered, will provide a useful future resource, even if the link expires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the footer that you want to add the clear fix to:

```
#footer:after {content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;}
```

What you're basically saying here is that at the end of the #footer div, add some content and make it display block, then make it clear both. This will pull the footer down over all floating content.

Update of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/hjP6f/1/

.

Comment: Thanks, I always presumed the after had to be applied to lthe last element in the container, Thankyou very much!

Comment: there's simpler and more compatible method to do that I guess ^^

Comment: Cool. Now the OP has two options. Bonus.

Comment: I don't know whether it was you who downvoted this answer @MatTheCat but I'm not willing to get into a voting war with another answerer. I think both answers are good and valid.

Comment: It's not a voting war, there's just simpler and more compatible method.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, downvoting is to be used when you think the answer is incorrect. Perhaps that's the case for you. Anyway, I like your answer and I think it's good that the OP has two different, working, methods to do what he wants.

Comment: Sorry for that but it seems you have to edit your answer in order to allow me cancel the downvote ^^'

Answer (score 1):

Just add `overflow:hidden;` to #footer. It will establish a new formatting content which allow it to encompass its flotant children.

Comment: You shouldn't *downvote* for use of clearfix - it's the more stable option (though @Jamie Dixon's answer is missing the IE6/7 part of clearfix..). I also use `overflow: hidden` 99% of the time (because it's easy + it works and, let's face it, clearfix is clunky and unsemantic), but sometimes you can't use it: http://fordinteractive.com/misc/overflow/